# R dataframe: drop duplicates based on certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I have a dataframe looking as:

```
    Day           State     Element
1   2020-04-01    0         A
2   2020-04-01    0         B
3   2020-04-01    0         C
4   2020-04-01    1         C
```

I'd like to filter the duplicated rows, but only based on the columns `Day` and `Element`, and keep the rows where `State` is 1. My expected output is:

```
    Day           State     Element
1   2020-04-01    0         A
2   2020-04-01    0         B
3   2020-04-01    1         C
```

I've tried with `drop_duplicates` and `distinct` but there not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

`arrange` the data based on decreasing value of `State` (so 1 comes before 0) and use `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(Element, desc(State)) %>%
  #If you have values greater than 1 in `State` use
  #arrange(Element, State != 1) %>%
  distinct(Day, Element, .keep_all = TRUE)

#         Day State Element
#1 2020-04-01     0       A
#2 2020-04-01     0       B
#4 2020-04-01     1       C
```

To keep all the 1's in your data try :

```
df %>%
  group_by(Day, Element) %>%
  slice(if(any(State == 1)) which(State == 1) else 1L)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but in my case it's only keeping one row of the dataframes, not all the rows with 1s

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. You can try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**data**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "    Day           State     Element
1   2020-04-01    0         A
2   2020-04-01    0         B
3   2020-04-01    0         C
4   2020-04-01    1         C", header = T)
```

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Day, Element) %>% 
  arrange(State) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Day        State Element
#>   <chr>      <int> <chr>  
#> 1 2020-04-01     0 A      
#> 2 2020-04-01     0 B      
#> 3 2020-04-01     1 C
```

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[order(Element, Day, State)][, list(State = last(State)), by = list(Day, Element)]
#>           Day Element State
#> 1: 2020-04-01       A     0
#> 2: 2020-04-01       B     0
#> 3: 2020-04-01       C     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but it's not really working in my case...

Comment: Please provide an extended example