# How to remove duplicate rows in all but a few columns?

Tags: r

I need to remove duplicated rows where all values are duplicates apart from two columns. How do I go about this?

The posted solutions are along the lines of this:

```r
df[!duplicated(df[ , c("x","y")]),]
```

Where the duplicated rows are selected based on if the value appears again in the stated columns, i.e. `x` and `y` in the example above. Therefore the suggested answer by the person that closed my question is not helpful ([R dataframe: drop duplicates based on certain columns [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136331/r-dataframe-drop-duplicates-based-on-certain-columns)).

Some of my data is duplicated in all 40 columns except two. I would therefore like to use these two columns as the condition (to ignore that is). I can remove the duplicated rows if I don't take into account one column like the example below. Hence, the second suggested answer is also redundant ([Select all rows which are duplicates except for one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302683/select-all-rows-which-are-duplicates-except-for-one-column)).

```r
df[!duplicated(df[, -5]), ]
```

This is by using the column number but I can't get it to work for two columns.

Here is an example data frame where rows (see `x5`) `4`, `10` and `16` need to be removed since they are duplicated in each column except `x5` and `x6`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"),
                  x2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                  x3 = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3"),
                  x4 = c("35", "43", "33", "33", "63", "24", "14", "25", "77", "77", "94", "51", "34", "36", "55", "55", "73", "72"),
                  x5 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"),
                  x6 = c("XA", "XB", "XC", "XD", "XE", "XF", "XG", "XH", "XI", "XJ", "XK", "XL", "XM", "XN", "XO", "XP", "XQ", "XR"))
```

This is my desired outcome.

```r
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"),
                  x2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                  x3 = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C3"),
                  x4 = c("35", "43", "33", "63", "24", "14", "25", "77", "94", "51", "34", "36", "55", "73", "72"),
                  x5 = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "17", "18"),
                  x6 = c("XA", "XB", "XC", "XE", "XF", "XG", "XH", "XI", "XK", "XL", "XM", "XN", "XO", "XQ", "XR"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, I have added some example data now, thanks MrFlick. Ian, the problem is that I have two columns that I wish to ignore. I am not sure how to implement the previously posted solutions when there is more than one column to ignore.

Comment: Maybe you want `df1 %>% group_by(pick(x1:x4)) %>% summarize(across(x5:x6 , first))` You need to supply a rule to collapse each of the columns you are ignoring for duplicates. Here it takes the first values for the duplicated groups. But `df1[!duplicated(df1[ , c("x1","x2", "x3","x4")]),]` and `df1[!duplicated(df1[, -5:-6]), ] ` also seems to return the same thing. So it's unclear why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the below code, assuming that `Identifier`, `Suffix` are the variable on which you want to remove the duplicates, if you want only one variable i.e., `Identifier`, then keep it and remove `Suffix`

```
library(dplyr)

unique_df <- df_split |>
  distinct(Amount, Identifier, Suffix, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: OP requested to select by the two ignored columns, not the 38 de-duped ones. Maybe `df |> distinct(pick(-c(x,y), .keep_all = TRUE)`?